# Unable to get the value in force:outputfield on pageload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Below is my code:

```
<aura:component controller="AccountController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/slds221/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" />
    <aura:attribute name="edit" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="save" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cancel" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Account' }"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <center>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.edit}">
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Edit Info" class="slds-align_absolute-center" onclick="{!c.handleEdit}"/>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.save}">
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Save Info" class="slds-align_absolute-center" onclick="{!c.handleSave}"/>
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.cancel}">
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" class="slds-align_absolute-center" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}"/>
        </aura:if>
    </center>
    <div class="slds-form slds-form_stacked">
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Process Item" disabled="{!!v.save}">
                    <option value="1">Yes</option>
                    <option value="2">No</option>
                </lightning:select>
            </div>
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-id-03">Process Contact ?</label>
            Save: {!v.Account.Contact__c}
            <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.save}">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <force:inputField value="{!v.Account.Contact__c}" class="foo" >{!v.Account.Contact__c}</force:inputField>
                </div>
            </aura:renderIf>
            <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!!v.save}">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                  <force:outputField aura:id="accountLookupOutput" value="{!v.Account.Contact__c}"/>
                </div>
            </aura:renderIf>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

My Js.

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var getaccountdata = component.get("c.getAccount");
        getaccountdata.setParams({ "Id": component.get("v.recordId")});
        getaccountdata.setCallback(this, function(response){      
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.Account",response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(getaccountdata);
    }
```

Apex Code:

```
  @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount(String Id) {
        system.debug('AccId:-'+Id);
        return [select Id,Contact__c from Account WHERE ID =:Id Limit 1];
    }
```

I get the associated data for that account and then i set it back to the account attribute.

But on page load I dont see the value in force:outputfield even though that account has that value populated in field.

Can anyone help me on this? if I missed something here
I tried to put force:output field at the top as well but still the same its blank

While selecting any value in the force:inputfield, the outputfield gets populated but not while the page loads

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error(s)?

Comment: No nothing in the console i checked. From the input field when i select any value i see that gets populated in output field but on the page load, nothing appears it is just blank

Comment: Share the Apex code as well;

Comment: just pasted in the question

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the issue, in the apex controller for the lookup fields, I need to use the related fields as well

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount(String Id) {
        system.debug('AccId:-'+Id);
        return [select Id,Contact__r.Name from Account WHERE ID =:Id Limit 1];
    }
```

Thanks @itzmukeshy7